# How to cite a reference intelligently for Springer Journal？

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

The reference are defined in the way shown in the figure, I just don't know how to cite it intelligently. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Are you talking about cross-referencing, as the tag says, or citing sources, which is different? Either way, please post code and not a picture of code, which nobody can experiment with to answer your question. Preferably, post it in the form of code for a minimal document which is ready-to-compile and reproduces the issue you want help with.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using LaTeX as you use commands such as `\textbf{}`. However, your code doesn't otherwise look like LaTeX at all. In any case, you can't cite references set that way intelligently. It is not possible. Also, do not use `\def` in LaTeX documents unless you are really, really sure you need to and you are really, really sure you aren't overwriting anything. two-letter font switches are 20+ years obsolete and ought not be used in LaTeX.  Never hard-code numbers when enumerating things.